# How can I redirect keyboard input (stdin) to audio device?

Tags: sound, redirect

I'd like to know how can I redirect my keyboard input to my audio device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more detail, I'll recommend `pacat`.

Comment: Why does it not count as an answer? 'pacat' is installed on the Ubuntu systems I've looked at and it takes stdin and redirects it to the pulse audio server.